# Links in PDF generated by PDFMake do not redirect to embedded link

Tags: pdfmake

I am using PDFMake (pdfmake v0.1.50) to generate my PDFs in a NodeJS and AngularJS application. The links in the generated PDF do not redirect to the embedded link. They redirect to the downloaded file's location path. This is a simple snippet as an example.

```
const docDefinition = {
  content: [
    {
      text: 'Sample Report For Testing',
      link: 'https://www.google.com/',
    }
  ],
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(fileName);
```

Should any other attributes be added to the link to make them work as external links?

Answer (score 0):

var dd = {
content: [{
text: 'Sample Report For Testing '
},
{ text: 'Google link',  link: 'https://www.google.com/', color: 'blue'}
]

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).